# Hiding and revealing images onload

Tags: javascript, events

I'm working on a simple script that will hide my images until they're fully loaded, then reveal them.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i=0; i<document.images.length; i++){                   
        document.images[i].style.visibility="hidden";
        document.images[i].addEventListener("load", function(i){
            document.images[i].visibility="visible"; 
        }, false);
     } 
});
```

For some reason, when the loop gets to the `addEventListener` part, firebug tells me that `document.images[i]` is `undefined`. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why you are not using jQuery event system ?

Comment: Can I ask, as seeing you're already using jquery, why you're not using it for the remaining part of the code?

Comment: Just realized that should be document.images[i].style.visibility. Doesn't fix the problem, though.

Comment: Just working on learning the core language atmo. Does having jQuery loaded interfere with that in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `this` inside the addEventListener handler.

```
document.images[i].addEventListener("load", function(){
                this.visibility="visible"; 
                }, false);
```

you can also try

```
document.images[i].onload = function(){
             this.visibility="visible";
      };
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
$(function () {
  $('img').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  $('img').on('load', function () {
    $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
  });
});
```

and have a look at [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)